# Access control error using Strongloop and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, openshift, strongloop

I am using the StrongLoop and MongoDB cartridges on the OpenShift cloud and I am unable to use the Explorer interface to query and manipulate resources in my collection.

I have created a simple model definition and deployed everything on OpenShift.  The MongoDB version is 2.4.9. MongoDB is started with the command-line:

```
mongod --auth -f /var/lib/openshift/<openshift-account>/mongodb//conf/mongodb.conf run
```

The .conf file referenced above is:

```
# mongodb.conf

bind_ip = <redacted>
#port = 27017

dbpath=/var/lib/openshift/<redacted>/mongodb/data/

pidfilepath=/var/lib/openshift/<redacted>/mongodb/pid/mongodb.pid

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = false

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#oplog = 0

# Diagnostic/debugging option
#nocursors = true

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Disable the HTTP interface (Defaults to localhost:27018).
nohttpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Accout token for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-token = <token>

# Server name for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-name = <server-name>

# Ping interval for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-interval = <seconds>

# Replication Options

# in replicated mongo databases, specify here whether this is a slave or master
#slave = true
#source = master.example.com
# Slave only: specify a single database to replicate
#only = master.example.com
# or
#master = true
#source = slave.example.com

# Address of a server to pair with.
#pairwith = <server:port>
# Address of arbiter server.
#arbiter = <server:port>
# Automatically resync if slave data is stale
#autoresync
# Custom size for replication operation log.
#oplogSize = 10
# Size limit for in-memory storage of op ids.
#opIdMem = <bytes>

# Specific configuration for openshift cartridge
smallfiles = true
quiet = true
```

Using the Explore UI, I am attempting a GET of all objects.  I expected to receive an empty result, but I am receiving an access control error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "MongoError",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "not authorized for query on admin.ACL",
    "stack": "MongoError: not authorized for query on admin.ACL\n    at Object.toError (/var/lib/openshift/544ecf5f4382ec1dcc0002ec/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)\n    at /var/lib/openshift/544ecf5f4382ec1dcc0002ec/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:700:54\n    at Cursor.close (/var/lib/openshift/544ecf5f4382ec1dcc0002ec/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:989:5)\n    at commandHandler (/var/lib/openshift/544ecf5f4382ec1dcc0002ec/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:700:21)\n    at /var/lib/openshift/544ecf5f4382ec1dcc0002ec/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1916:9\n    at Server.Base._callHandler (/var/lib/openshift/544ecf5f4382ec1dcc0002ec/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:448:41)\n    at /var/lib/openshift/544ecf5f4382ec1dcc0002ec/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:481:18\n    at MongoReply.parseBody (/var/lib/openshift/544ecf5f4382ec1dcc0002ec/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)\n    at null.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/544ecf5f4382ec1dcc0002ec/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:439:20)\n    at emit (events.js:95:17)"
  }
}
```

Here is an excerpt from the mongodb log file prompted by the request:

```
Thu Oct 30 08:06:56.633 [conn9] assertion 16550 not authorized for query on <redacted>.ACL ns:<redacted>.ACL query:{ $query: { model: "Media", property: { $in: [ "find", "*" ] }, accessType: { $in: [ "READ", "*" ] } }, orderby: { _id: 1 } }
Thu Oct 30 08:07:13.949 [conn13]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "admin", nonce: "<redacted>", key: "<redacted>" }
Thu Oct 30 08:07:14.717 [conn13] command admin.$cmd command: { listDatabases: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) R:458 W:106047 r:48 reslen:285 136ms
Thu Oct 30 08:07:14.826 [conn13] command admin.$cmd command: { $eval: CodeWScope( function (){ return db.getCollectionNames(); }, {}), args: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) W:106944 reslen:92 106ms
Thu Oct 30 08:07:14.918 [conn14]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "admin", nonce: "<redacted>", key: "<redacted>" }
```

I receive the same error when trying to create a resource in the collection using the Explorer interface.  Note the username it is authenticating is admin, which is not the username and credentials I include in my datasources.json:

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "cloudMongoDB": {
    "host": "<redacted>",
    "port": "27017",
    "url": "mongodb://<redacted:27017/<redacted",
    "username": "<not-user-admin>",
    "password": "<redacted>",
    "name": "cloudMongoDB",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "database": "<redacted>"
  }
}
```

One confusing element is that the username and credentials used in datasources.json are not admin (as listed in the error log), but another user who has the readwrite role for the database holding the collection queried.  The admin user is setup according to openshift cartridge defaults. So the admin user does not have access to the target database.

I am able to browse the database from a Mongo client tool using the same credentials I have used in datasources.json, including adding data to the database.

So it appears that the username and password from datasources.json are not being integrated into the Strongloop authentication.  Do I need to explicitly add the credentials into the url in order for them to be used to authenticate?

I am interested in understanding what the message means.  What user administration steps do I need to take to configure StrongLoop to access MongoDB from the explorer application?

MW

---

Update with Solution: 
When I changed the url in datasources.json to the form "mongodb://username:password@... StrongLoop authenticated as my non-admin user and move further along. I found a typo in the role I had granted the user ("the correct role is readWrite, while I had originally granted readwrite").  Once I fixed the role definition, I am now able to use  the StrongLoop explorer with MongoDB.

I then removed the url parameter from my datasources.json and found that StrongLoop used the database, username, password to build its own URL and connect as expected. It seems the url field overrides other fields in the datasource definition.  For the moment, everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update, we will clarify that last part to our docs too.